# How to get increment id on current page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, increment-id

I need to redirect to get data relevant to current increment ID of Order entity? So how I find current increment ID?

```
public function viewAction() {      
    $this->loadLayout();
    if($increment_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('increment_id')) {
        Mage::register('current_increment_id',$increment_id);
        $this->_setActiveMenu('casestation');
        $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('casestation/adminhtml_print')
        );
    }
    return $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Page page directed according to above function. I need to add button here and want to get order details on current increment ID.

Comment: Which increment id are you talking about ? Order entity ? Product entity ? Category Entity ? Please specify or your question will be flagged as unclear.

Comment: @DigitalPianism Order entity

Comment: from which page you want to get that particular ID ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to assign current increment-id to variable.

```
 $currentIncrementId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('increment_id');
```

This will help to assign current increment ID into new variable.